# Generic extension method in mongoose. error: method is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I am trying to create generic extension method on all mongoose model. But I am unable to avail method on model when use runtime.

I have implemented as following.

```
mongoose.model.prototype.findOneAndUpsert = async function <
  T extends mongoose.Document<any, {}> 
>(
  filter?: FilterQuery<T>,
  update?: UpdateQuery<T>,
  options?: QueryOptions | null,
  callback?: (err: any, doc: T | null, res: any) => void,
): Promise<T> {
  const model = this as mongoose.Model<T>;
  if (filter.id) {
    return model.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, callback);
  } else {
    return model.findById((await model.create((update as any).$set)).id);
  }
};
```

Is this possible or not supported at all? Or I am doing in a wrong way?

I am trying to use it as following. DatasourceModel is a Typegoose model.

```
DatasourceModel.findOneAndUpsert(someParams)
```

Error I am getting is as below.

```
TypeError: datasource_1.DatasourceModel(...).findOneAndUpsert is not a function
```

I have declared mongoose module as following which helps during compile time. But not during runtime.

`declare module 'mongoose' { interface Model<T> extends NodeJS.EventEmitter, AcceptsDiscriminator { findOneAndUpsert<T>(  filter?: FilterQuery<T>, update?: UpdateQuery<T>, options?: QueryOptions | null, callback?: (err: any, doc: T | null, res: any) => void, ): Promise<T>; } }`

Comment: from what i know, you also have to declare that function in the mongoose module

Comment: I have updated module declaration in question. It is helping during compile time. But at runtime still error is same. Do I need anything else as well?

Comment: something i noticed, you wrote `mongoose.model` instead of `mongoose.Model`, is this just an typo in the example, or is this actually how you try to do it? because `mongoose.model` is an function just to "compile" the schema into an model, and `mongoose.Model` is what is actually the model class (where all the functions like `find` are)

Comment: Oh ok. That might be an error. It is not typo. I had copy pasted as is. Will check that soon.